# Use css to change the image path got from server for different breakpoints using media query

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I have one backend REST API service which returns the content as well as the logo for the content as below

```
[
{
"header":"Your Reviews",
"content":"reviews details",
"logo":"reviews.png"
},
{
"header":"Your benefits",
"content":"benefits details",
"logo":"benefits.png"
}
]
```

For each data, there is logic to get the artpath as "`/assets/<breakpoint>/<replace_logo_name>`" for example "`/assets/desktop/reviews.png`" or "`/assets/tablet/reviews.png`" or "`/assets/mobile/reviews.png`". I.e. different logo image for differnet breakpoints. I am using @media queries and I can either use  tag or css background property to render logo image on screen.

However I don't want to use javascript to change the logo path for diffrent devices or browser resize. I am using javascript to only read the json and build the markup. Can I use pure css (using media query or something else) to change the logo path as per the breakpoints?

Please advice.

Comment: No. While CSS can change the appearance of what you display in your page it has no ability to change what you receive from the server. It *can* use @media queries to access different background-images of elements, or provide different `content` to generated content/pseudo-elements (`::before`, `::after` etc); but that may or may not work in your case.

Comment: thanks, this is what i thought. I would still not take javascript route, instead of that i am planning to create separate css class for all these categories using media query and in the markup generation logic, i will set these class name by striping the ".png"

Answer (score 0):

If you set the image as a `background-image` for a div, you could toggle which image is displayed via media queries.